# Push elements of

Tags: javascript

This is, I believe a very simple question for a JS programmer. Given the following array of objects named "categories"

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "FURNITURE", 
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "AUTOMOTIVE",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "UPHOLSTERY",
    }
]
```

I want to push the "name" on the "selectedCategories" array below where "id" === "id"

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

Below is my attempt to solve this, but ... not working..

```
for (let i = 0; i < selectedCategories.length; i++) {
    for(let y = 0; y < categories.length; y++){
      selectedCategories.name = categories[y].name
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to slice selected name from first array ?

Comment: Please read [ask] to learn how to write a good post title.

Comment: I need to populate the selectedCategories array with the name take from the first array where id's are matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
selectedCategories = selectedCategories.map(el => {
    const searchEl = categories.find(e => e.id === el.id);
    if (searchEl)
        return { ...el, name: searchEl.name }
    return el;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const categories = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "FURNITURE", 
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "AUTOMOTIVE",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "UPHOLSTERY",
    }
];

var selectedCategories = [
    {
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
    }
];

selectedCategories = selectedCategories.map(
  selectedCategory => categories.find(category => category.id === selectedCategory.id),
);

console.log(selectedCategories);
```

Comment: This would push `undefined` into the `selectedCategories` array if there are `id`s not found in the `categories` array.